# mod_rewrite before of after developing application

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite

I am trying to better understand how to incorporate mod_rewrite into a web applications development life cycle.

The question I am trying to understand is:

1. Do you build your application and then setup mod_rewrite after the fact?
2. Is it more appropriate to consider mod_rewrite along the way while you develop your application?

Answer (score 3):

mod_rewrite is a substantial part of your application. If it doesn't handle just trivial requests, but for example establishes a front controller, then of course you have to have planned your application structure to know what mod_rewrite is supposed to do.

Comment: Can you elaborate on establishing a front controller?

Comment: A front controller is the file you direct all requests to, which handles all of the routing (Deciding what PHP code to run based on the requested URL). For an example, look at WordPress -- all requests are rewritten to `index.php` which decides what code to run and what template to use to render the output.

Comment: Thanks, I understand that part.  Is there any consideration to make with using a single front door in terms of performance and scalability?

Comment: Please [don't use signatures or taglines](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures) in your posts. Additionally, it is unnecessary to address you post to Chris. You are implicitly doing so by answering his question.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever I'm building an application - first thing what I do is to redirect any /foo/bar/ or /foo/bar.html into a PHP index.php?path=foo/bar. More detailed setup ( for example for images etc. ) I do when I need it